# Correctly Load an Image into an Existing storyboard UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I am using an array to try to load images into specific UIImageViews. I have 10 UIImageViews set up on my storyboard.

I also have a Game Over method that runs whenever the frame of one UIImageView intersects with another UIImageView. For some reason, whenever I try to use the array to load my UIImageViews, my Game Over method immediately triggers. I can't figure out why. As soon as I remove the initWithImage line, the game runs normally. Any ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  KanaCharacters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"],...
                  nil];


int imageDisplay = arc4random_uniform([KanaCharacters count]);

Monster1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[KanaCharacters objectAtIndex:imageDisplay]];
}

-(void) Collision
{
   if ((CGRectIntersectsRect(Monster1.frame, Ship.frame)) && (Monster1Hit==NO))
   {
      [self GameOver];
   }
}

-(void)GameOver
{
  WinOrLose.hidden=NO;
  WinOrLose.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Lose!"];
 }
```

Comment: it is hard to understand what is going on from snippet, but if you have the uiimageview (is monster1 in storyboard?) in storyboard you shouldn't alloc & init again in viewDidLoad. Call setImage instead, bc otherwise your new UIImageView won't even be added to viewcontroller's view, you will need to manually add it with addSubview.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's a bit tough to explain. You are correct, Monster1 is already an ImageView within the storyboard. I thought setImage too, but it isn't a method for UIImageView, only for UIImage. Should I be setting the image from the array to a UIImage, and then somehow using that variable for the UIImageView? (Sorry, new to this!)

Comment: image is a property of [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image) so you can call setImage on it or you can call monster1.image = [UIImage ...]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Collision if firing once an image in Monster1 and Ship.frame. 
This is because I suspect your Monster is being placed where your ship is?

you may want to move the ship or the monster before you add the image into the view.